# append to keystore file

Tags: java, file, append, keystore

Anyone has got any idea how can I append keys to a keystore file please in java?

Comment: Documentation at http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot append keys to keystore, one keystore contains only one key.

I suppose you want to append certificate chain - you may do that with "keystore -import" command.

Comment: A keystore can contain multiple entries.  Any entry can either be a private key or a trusted public cert in combination with the identity of an entity.